Send screenshot to php file, and send it by email
I need to send a screenshot from a js scrip to a php file. Then, my php script send me an email with the screen.
I use fetch API to send the screenshot. Then I use the library phpMailer for my php script.
For now, I recieve my email with my body and my attachment file. But when I upload and try to open the file, my applications (photoshop and windows photo app) all says "this is not a .png file"
I don't really understand the encode decode, jsonparse etc, so i think it come from this part.
Can somewone explain to me more clearly ?
Thanks a lot, there is my js and php script :
JS
var canvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas');

async function sendEmail() {

    var url = '/wp-content/themes/julietcolombe/sendEmail.php';
    var drawingData = canvas.toDataURL();
    var image = encodeURIComponent(drawingData);

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('drawingData', image);

    fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: formData })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (body) {
            console.log(body);
        });

}

PHP
$drawingData = isset($_POST['drawingData']) ? $_POST['drawingData'] : false;

$imageData = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $drawingData));
$imageName = uniqid() . '.png';
$imagePath = $tempFolder . $imageName;

file_put_contents($imagePath, $imageData);

 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "***";
        $mail->Password = "***";
        $mail->Port = 25;

        $mail->From = "***e@gmail.com";
        $mail->addAddress("**e@gmail.com");

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Screenshot';
        $mail->Body = 'New screen by : xx ';

        $mail->addAttachment($imagePath, $imageName, 'base64', 'image/png');

        $mail->send();


Check your assumptions – verify that the uploaded image data is actually valid when it reaches the server. If it's not, then the email part isn't going to fix it.

@Synchro it seems ok to me, because when I debug it (console.log(image)) from my js file, his format start with "data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...."
And it's also the same when I debug it (echo $drawingData) from my php file.

OK, so go to the next step and look at the message as it's sent (set SMTPDebug = 2), and you should be able to see the encoded image as it's sent. It's not difficult to extract the image from the encoding and check it's the same as what you put in.
